# How to use string.format with eval in the aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, eval

I have a repeater in my web page like following

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="AccountScrollRepeater" onitemdatabound="AccountRepeater_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr class="primary-BL2" style="text-align:left">
        <td style="width:70px"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="AccountNoLabel" Text='<%# Eval("AccountNo") %>'></asp:Label></td>
        <td style="width:40px"><asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="CustomerHyperLink" NavigateUrl="" Text='<%# Eval("CustId") %>' Enabled="false"></asp:HyperLink></td>
        ...
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I would like to set the NavigateUrl of the CustomerHyperLink to following expression,

```
string.Format(AppSetting.Instance.GetSearchDetailUrl(SearchTypeEnum.Customer), '<%# Eval("CustNo") %>');
```

My question is instead of setting the NavigateUrl in the code behind, how do I put this in the aspx page?

Comment: Why do you want this on the `.aspx` if it works with code behind?

Comment: How do I get the hyperlink from code behind?

Comment: In the repeater `OnItemDataBound` event handler, use `(HyperLink)AccountScrollRepeater.FindControl("CustomerHyperLink");`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here we go

```
NavigateUrl ='<%# String.Format (AppSetting.Instance.GetSearchDetailUrl(SearchTypeEnum.Customer), Eval("intSMCID")) %>';
```